# What annotation in model should I use to show TextArea instead TextField in the View for editing particular string property of the model?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I create view for editing a `class Person` object. In `class Person` there is property:

```
 [DisplayName("Notes")]
        public string Notes { get; set; }
```

In the `Edit.cshtml` view I want to edit this property:

```
  <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Notes, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Notes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Notes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

it works fine excepting `@Html.EditorFor(...)` shows by default `TextField` for strings. For this one I would like it to show `TextArea` how this can be achieved?

**Question**: How to achieve showing `TextArea` instead of `TextField` for particular class property. Preferably by annotation in model

EDIT:

Upper `TextArea` when I use `[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]` annotation and `EditorFor`. Lower when I use `@Html.TextAreaFor...` in the view.

[image]

EDIT2:

For the code under: It applies css for `EditorFor` method but dose not for `TextAreaFor`,

```
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Notes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Notes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Notes,
                  new {
                      htmlAttributes = new {
                          @class = "form-control",
                          rows = 10,
                          columns = 40
                      }
                  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]` Annotation for your model Property.

```
[DisplayName("Notes")]
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string Notes { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can I describe how many lines I want? Your solution worked better then `TextAreaFor` because it shows pretty `TextArea`.

Comment: There is no build-in solution. You can use css to specify height of textarea or You can make custom editor template with code from @Ehsan Sajjad answer and add annotation to use this template `[UIHint("CustomTemplateName")]`

Comment: How to define this css multiline template please show just any example.

Comment: Add in your css file `textarea {height: 300px;}`

Comment: It turned out t be fairly easy, I posted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Then you need to use `Html.TextAreaFor()` helper not `Editorfor()`:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Notes, 
                  new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", 
                                               rows= 10, 
                                               columns= 40 } 
                  })
```

or:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Notes, new { @class = "form-control",
                                              rows= 10, 
                                              columns= 40 })
```

See [**Html.TextAreaFor()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.textareaextensions.textareafor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks that worked but for some reason it showed ugly TextArea. When I used `[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]` above property in the model it showed pretty textArea but only 2 rows long.

Comment: you need to check it is applying css class or not.

Comment: It does not apply css style for it I showed my code in the EDIT 2 in OP and result in the EDIT1(but additionally now there is another ugly TextArea form last line of EDIT2 code)

Comment: @Yoda can you check using firebug inspector or chrome dev tools to see that css class added for textarea or not?

Comment: I posted the answer it looks that `TextAreaFor` is unecessary. One can use `EditorFor`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create TextArea by `EdtiorFor` so the style will be kept.

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Notes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", rows = 20 } })
```